# Better way to remove matched items from a list

Tags: c#, list

In c#, when I want to remove some items from a list, i do it in the following way,

```
List<Item> itemsToBeRemoved = new List<Item>();
foreach(Item item in myList)
{
   if (IsMatching(item)) itemsToBeRemoved.Add(item);
}

foreach(Item item in itemsToBeRemoved)
{
   myList.Remove(item);
}
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: prefer solutions in c# 2.0 without LINQ. thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, you could call the method that does exactly what you want.

```
myList.RemoveAll(IsMatching);
```

Generally it is "better" to use the method that does exactly what you want rather than re-inventing it yourself.

Comment: obviously I have overlooked this method.. thanks!!

Answer (score 12):

```
myList.RemoveAll(x=> IsMatching(x));
```

Comment: And if you want, you don't even have to use the lambda. The compiler will automatically convert "IsMatching" to Predicate<T>.

Comment: +1 But this not LINQ, this is just method on List<T>.

Comment: Also, why do you say "if you can use LINQ"?  What does this have to do with LINQ?

Comment: Sorry, I was halfway typing up another version of my answer, when I replaced it with this. Forgot to remove the intro.

Comment: Following his example, I think you want myList, rather than itemsToBeRemoved.  Still, good answer, +1

Comment: @Matt, you are correct. I really need more coffee.

Comment: RemoveAll() is a method if List<T>, so it has nothing to do with LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit of an improvement using Linq.

```
var itemsToRemove = myList.Where(item => IsMatching(item)).ToList();
foreach(Item item in itemsToBeRemoved)
{
   myList.Remove(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about reverting your logic, adding items which doesn't match and just use the result collection?

```
List<Item> itemsTaken = new List<Item>();
foreach(Item item in myList)
{
   if (!IsMatching(item)) itemsTaken.Add(item);
}

// use itemsTaken as if it were myList with items removed
```

Comment: that depends on the ratio of number of items to be removed and items to be retained in the list.

Answer (score 1):

What I used to do is the create a reverse for-loop:

```
for (int i=myList.Count-1; i>=0; i--)
{
  if (IsMatching(myList[i]))
    myList.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

But I'm sure there are more elegant ways using LINQ.

Comment: I got downvoted too!  What the frig!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Jakers said, and assuming you are on .Net 3:

```
myList = myList.Where(item => !IsMatching(item)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(Item singleItem in new List<Item>(allItems))
{
  if(IsMatching(singleItem))
     allItems.Remove(singleItem);
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I didn't think you could modify an array while iterating over it using foreach.

Comment: He's not modifying it. He's made a copy, is iterating over the copy, and is modifying the original.

Comment: Ahh, so he is.  Didn't notice that the first time.